# Homework question put on hold for "demanding an answer" even though, I did show what my own thinking/approach to the problem was?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, homework

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410778/how-would-someone-use-curves-as-an-input-to-a-supervised-learning-model) about a question that came up in a test was put on hold, presumably because I am "demanding an answer". But I'm not, I clearly explained what my thinking was  and how it differed from the provided solution. I also explain why I don't understand the solution (PCA would just transform the input space, not breakdown into usable features).

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I think your question is perfectly understandable.  Due to the flaws in the quotation and the lack of any real context (which often helps overcome such problems), I'm a little uncertain about its appropriateness for our site.  It's not even apparent that the form in which these "curves" are given you is even amenable to PCA: the implicit assumption in the answer appears to be that they are all sampled at common times.  Moreover, it's amenable to many different (good) answers, which doesn't work well here. Perhaps focusing your question on the PCA issue might help us understand and answer it.

Comment: I agree w/ @whuber. I might have closed as *unclear* or *too broad*, as I'm not sure it's answerable from what's provided. That said, note that the various closing options all come w/ stock comments that may or may not actually be a good fit for the specific post. Ie, I wouldn't take the "demanding an answer" too literally.

Comment: @whuber I've added context. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, it does.  At the same time I was completing a comment to your question indicating why it's not answerable in its general form.